# How to make this type of grid system with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I'm trying to make a grid system like this https://www.google.com/about/careers/, anybody know how to make this in the right way and also it supports mobile?

Comment: Demo attached, verify at your end.

Answer (score 0):

**Please see the demo in full page mode also**

```css
img {
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container-fluid">

        <p>Please see demo in full page mode.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/careers-homepage-datacenter360.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <img src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/careers-homepage-datacenter360.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <img src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/careers-homepage-datacenter360.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <img src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/careers-homepage-datacenter360.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <img src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/careers-homepage-datacenter360.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/careers-homepage-datacenter360.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for  your answer but there is a problem, unequal spacing between pictures. How can we solve that? @anil-panwar

Comment: you can inspect the element in browser and can figure out the padding or margin of the col-md-xyz classes. If this has solved your purpose then do upvote and mark answer accepted..Good luck